# Minimum number of cycles for a cache miss

Tags: caching

Question:

Determine the minimum number of cycles for a cache miss, where the fully associative cache has a better performance than the 2-way cache.

Can someone please explain to me how I would go about calculating this? I have the values for:

- the number of cycles required to complete the sequence of memory accesses assuming 1) a 2-way associative cache and 2) a fully associative cache
- access time for a n-way associative cache
- total access time for a cache miss
- size of cache memory (in blocks)
- size of main memory (in blocks)
- access time for a direct-mapped cache (in cycles)

Possible calculations I have considered using:

- average memory access time
- cycles per instruction
- miss rate
- miss penalty

Thank you!